# Calling a lambda within a NestJS project

Tags: lambda, nestjs, serverless

I have a project with NestJS, Lambda, Serverless architecture. So each Nest application is a lambda.

The problem I have, is that I need to call inside a lambda, to another lambda of the same project.
I am doing it with invoke. The call goes in fine, I see it in the logs, but the problem is that I get an empty client-context. So I am failing in the parameters issue.

If anyone has done it and has a suggestion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just call to the function with the proper params.

Sample: if the endpoint of your lambda is:

```js
   @Post('/check')
    async check(@Body() request: StoreRequest) {
        console.log('stores/check:', request.id);
        // call to implementation logic
        return await this.storeService.check(request);
    }
```

and we need call it from Customers module:

```js
@Injectable()
export class Customers {

    constructor(
        // this one is that you looking for: inject the service
        private storeService: StoreService
    ) {
    }

    public async getBranchInfo(storeId: number): Promise<BranchResponse> {

    // call to the lambda check implementation in the same project
         const request = {id: 1234}
         const store = this.storeService.check(request)
    //

    }
}
```

WARNING: The code doesn't run.